# Django: One model, different forms and widgets?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I try to find the best way to have a field with multiple content types.
What I've done so far is a Contact model with a contacttype CharField:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    CONTACT_TYPES = (
        ('email', 'Email'),
        ('phone', 'Phone'),
        ('address', 'Address'),
        ('facebook', 'Facebook'),
        ('linkedin', 'LinkedIn'),
        ('youtube', 'Youtube'),
        ('twitter', 'Twitter'),
        ('google', 'Google'),
     )
     teammember = models.ForeignKey(TeamMember)
     description = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
     contacttype = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices= CONTACT_TYPES, default='email')
     contact = models.TextField()
```

My goal is to let the user add different contact informations, which'll be listed on the profile page, but with only one model.

I was thinking about a class for each ModelForm:

```
class ContactForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ModelForm, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)
        self.contacttype = ""

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['description', 'contact']
        widgets = {'contact': TextInput()}

    def clean_contacttype(self):
        return self.contacttype

class ContactEmailForm(ContactForm):

    def __init__(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)
        self.contacttype = "email"

    class Meta(ContactForm.Meta):
        model = Contact
        fields = ['description', 'contact']
        widgets = {'contact': EmailInput()}

class ContactPhoneForm(ContactForm):

    def __init__(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)
        self.contacttype = "phone"

    class Meta(ContactForm.Meta):
        model = Contact
        fields = ['description', 'contact']
        widgets = {'contact': TextInput()}

    def clean_contact(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ContactForm, self).clean()
        contact = cleaned_data.get("contact")
        # Perform some phone number validations
        return contact
```

Then, in my view, I would choose the correct form depending on the request argument (ex: /contact/add/email or /contact/add/phone).

I'm trying to find the most elegant way to do this, so any help is welcome.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use one html file, then this is one of solutions.

```
class YourView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'your_template.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if context['type'] == 'phone':
            context['form'] = ContactPhoneForm
        elif ...
```

if you set your view, then

```
<form action="{% url "your view" %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
{% if form.contenttype == 'phone' %}
    {% include "partials/contact_phone_form.html" with form=form %}
{% elif form.contenttype == 'email' %}
    {% include "partials/contact_email_form.html" with form=form %}
{% else %}
    do something.
{% endif %}
</form>
```

and, contact_phone_form.html and contact_email_form is looks like

```
anything.
<input name='phone'>
anything.
```

this solution is for one template, multi form.

if you want to do multi template for specific form, then you can use this.

```
class YourView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'your_template.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if context['type'] == 'phone':
            template_name = 'phone_form_template.html'
        elif context['type'] == 'email':
            template_name = 'email_form_template.html'
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use **forms.Form** depending on the request argument like:

/contact/add/?type=email or /contact/add/?type=phone

and so you can use it like (not tested code):

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateUserquestionnaireForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if "email" in self.data:
            ... do some thing like change contact type or widget
        if "phone" in self.data:
            ... do some thing like change contact type or widget
```